# Как сделать кастомный endpoint со своими параметрами в ApiPlatform?

Tags: php, api, symfony, api-platform.com

Всем привет,

У меня есть задание взять данные из внешнего апи и показать их на сайте с использованием `symfony` и `Api platform`.

Пользователь выбирает даты и получает результат с внешнего апи. Я сделал приложение в виде обычного rest, но в задании есть обязательное условие использовать Api platform. И я не понимаю каким образом его здесь использовать? Единственное моё предположение это:

Api platform должен быть как обёртка над внешним api с которого я буду брать данные, в нём будет свой endpoint например `api/get/{startDate}/{endDate}` и этот endpoint будет возвращать json данные для клиента, буду использовать reactjs. Но в этом случае я не могу понять как сделать endpoint со своими параметрами, api platform везде пихает параметр id, а мне надо только те 2 параметра которые я укажу. И я не использую сущность в этом проекте так как ничего не записываю в базу, а api platform нужно конфигурировать через сущность. В общем не совсем понимаю как это сделать. С api platform особо не знаком, и не могу найти как сделать такой роут `api/get/{startDate}/{endDate}`.

Вроде бы как достать данные можно при помощи Data Providers, а как тогда создать контроллер к этому провайдеру без сущности?

Answer (score 0):

Вам ничего не мешает написать что-то подобное, не ссылаясь ни на какие сущности:

```
/**
 * Метод делает что-то (его описание, будет title-ом для данного метода на `/api/doc`).
 *
 * @Rest\Get("/{startDate}/{endDate}/")
 *
 * @Rest\View(statusCode=200)
 *
 * @SWG\Response(
 *     response=200,
 *     description="Успешный запрос"
 * )
 *
 * @SWG\Response(
 *     response=400,
 *     description="Невалидный параметр, скажите об этом",
 *     @SWG\Schema(
 *          @SWG\Property(property="success", type="boolean"),
 *          @SWG\Property(property="code", type="string"),
 *          @SWG\Property(property="data", type="object"),
 *          @SWG\Property(property="message", type="string")
 *     )
 * )
 *
 * @SWG\Response(
 *     response=404,
 *     description="Что-то не найдено",
 *     @SWG\Schema(
 *          @SWG\Property(property="success", type="boolean"),
 *          @SWG\Property(property="code", type="string"),
 *          @SWG\Property(property="data", type="object"),
 *          @SWG\Property(property="message", type="string")
 *     )
 * )
 */
 public function someAction(string $startDate, string $endDate) 
 { 
     /** Do something here... */ 
 }
```

Так же, вы можете указать общий роут у класса:

```
/**
 * @Route("/api/get")
 * @SWG\Tag(name="Название раздела для данного класса")
 */
 class YourClassController extends AbstractFOSRestController
```